# Is it possible to change the settings in android so that data is saved to the external SD card instead of the the phone's internal memory?

Tags: ram, sd-card

This problem has been annoying me for a while. When I download and install an app to my phone it defaults to the phone's internal memory. Not too big of a deal since I can move it afterwards. The problem comes after when the app has additional data it needs to install on to the device. That additional data always installs to the phone memory and I can't move it to the SD card.

For example: I install an app that is in total 1mb in size that I can move to the SD card. But the app downloads 300mb of data that stays on the internal memory that the app uses.

Is there a way to change it so that the data is downloaded to the SD?
I know that it's possible to re-partition the SD card and internal memory to make the internal memory bigger but I want to do that as a last resort.

Comment: there is a stack exchange site for andriod, probably that would be the right place for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO.
You'll need to re-partition your SD to make your internal memory bigger.

Answer (score 0):

No. The way android is set up, you have to install directly to internal. It's a part of the very core of the OS.